# IE11 and Safari didn't pass the authorization header to backend

Tags: java, spring, safari, internet-explorer-11

In my react app, i send a request to java backend. But when request send by IE11 and Safari, backend can't get the authorization header, the other headers can be obtained.

I tried to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin and withCrendentials in the axios. But doesn't work.

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: link,
    responseType: 'document',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        expires: expires,
        abc: 'abc'
   },
   withCredentials: true
})
```

Front end code:

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: link,
    responseType: 'document',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        expires: expires,
        abc: 'abc'
   }
})
```

Backend code:

```
httpRequest.getHeader("Expires") -> same as expires value in header
httpRequest.getHeader("abc") -> "abc"
httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization") -> always to be null when browser is IE11 and Safari
```

Comment: Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console? Besides, you could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1790). You could check if you have added the web site to IE's trusted site list and try to remove it. You could also try the workarounds in this [similar thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/891).

Answer (score 0):

Theres several reasons that can be the cause of this problem.
First of all, make sure those headers are present in the browser's request when you navigate with each browser. That's the most important thing.
You can check this by pressing f12 and choosing the Network tab. Be sure you have the button "Preserve log" selected. Navigate to where you want and search for the request you need, then analyze it. 
[Inspect Network tab on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9UHx.png)
If the browser don't use the header it's possible that the header isnt necessary at all. 
You can also check this using some software like Charles Proxy or similar. (https://www.charlesproxy.com/)
Second, the problem can be just the name of the header. Each browser can use different headers (even for the same request). The header you're looking for maybe isnt present in Safari or IE11 but the information you want is somewhere in that request. Search for it.